# What is the name of this power or value-oriented gameplay mechanic?

Tags: game-mechanics, balance, card-game, game-design

I would like to identify the name of a certain gameplay mechanism. It is fairly commonly seen but probably best illustrated with card games:

A game played with a pack of cards usually has card values ordered in the following way:

```
A > K > Q > J > 10 > 9 > 8 > 7 > 6 > 5 > 4 > 3 > 2
```

Sometimes the lowest-ranked card (in this case `2`) is specially ruled to trump the highest-ranked card (in this case `A`). Is there a proper name for such a mechanism?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing an extension of the rock-paper-scissors mechanic whereby every piece/card/token can defeat at least one other piece/card/token.

(Your question made me think of Stratego, and specifically of the few pieces like the low-ranked Spy who can defeat the otherwise-top-ranked Marshal and the Miner who can defuse bombs.)

Comment: yes, I believe you described something similiar as featured in Stratego, but I did not consider what I had in mind as an extension of that (rock-paper-scissors). An interesting perspective however.

Comment: "Exception" might be the word you're looking for; I'm not aware of any game-specific term that describes this particular situation.

Comment: The mathematical term for this is a "non-transitive" relation.

If the "beats" relation was transitive, then "Ace beats King" and "King beats 2" would give "Ace also beats 2" which we don't want here.

So if one player beats another according to a non-transitive rule, you might call the mechanic a "non-transitive victory condition"

(See other games like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice )

Answer (score 3):

It may be that it really is just referred to as **trumping**, and that the mechanism would simply be "having a **trump**", or **trump rule variation** as AttackingHobo suggested.

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump#Trumps_in_card_games) discusses the idea, but it seems to usually refer to suit trumping.

Comment: "Trump" usually refers to a card that beats everything that is not that card - So 2 is not a trump in the proposed rule of "A>K>Q>J>10>9>8>7>6>5>4>3 and K>Q>J>10>9>8>7>6>5>4>3>2 and 2>A".